# strange results when manually database copy to another server

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two servers same config differents ID,name,port and data folder (as services on windows)

I have manualy copied folders from Server1/data to Server2/data

I have restarted Server2 windows service and for checking if data are ok when I have tried this:

```
mysql -uroot -p -P 3307


mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+----------------------------------+
| Database                         |
+----------------------------------+
| information_schema               |
| ff5ef614920c0c57b6105c10fa27af00 |
| mysql                            |
| performance_schema               |
| sys                              |
+----------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE ff5ef614920c0c57b6105c10fa27af00
Database changed

mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+--------------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_ff5ef614920c0c57b6105c10fa27af00 |
+--------------------------------------------+
| cabafc1f4121f23f1889b4f02fe736e1           |
| cc301a28c4ce605bc2b873970ecc9556           |
| d1c89cb333001f0ad1594eb216ba6794           |
+--------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from cc301a28c4ce605bc2b873970ecc9556;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'ff5ef614920c0c57b6105c10fa27af00.cc301a28c4ce605bc2b873970ecc9556' doesn't exist
```

This happend only with second table named cc301a28c4ce605bc2b873970ecc9556

The first table and last table working good

Comment: @nCessity You are right: In your mentioned answer is the solution. So mi second table are innoDB ... and I have ommited to copy correctly ib_* files to Server2. Now I have copied ib_* files and working good. What you recommended ? to delete my question ? If necesary I will delete it

Comment: Same to @Mike Nakis ... What I can do now ? ... What is the good practice ? Need to delete mi question ?

Comment: you can delete it if you want to, but also you do not need to do anything.

Comment: I think they do get automatically deleted after a while.