# How to fix error "Table doesn't exist in engine"?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I installed a new version of Xampp which is 8.1.10 after that I tried to retrieve the database of old xampp folder from `xampp/mysql/data` and my main database folder that I named `lalaigacafe` also I tried to make a new data from `xampp/mysql/backup` folder and I copied `ibdata1` file into it, but it keep telling me an error message which is "#1932 - Table 'my_table_name' doesn't exist in engine".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [You should not copy `ibdata`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48786940/mysql-doesnt-start-after-copying-the-ibdata1-file)

Comment: I tried to not copy it but also it keep telling me the same error.

Comment: [Tool to export data with all relational data?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40461/tool-to-export-data-with-all-relational-data)

Comment: MySQL also stores information in the database `information_schema` (take a look at the output of: `select * from information_schema.tables;`, in a working database)   Currently you do not have that information, because you copied `ibdata1`.

Comment: @Luuk First thanks for trying helping me. But those two questions not helping me as I need.

Comment: Do you still have access to your old database (via MySQL client) ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. I Just have access to the old folders only.

Comment: Then you probably lost your data as is explained in this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48790734/724039   (I do not know a way to get your data back, and if it is possible to do so, it will be a lot of work and need DEEP knowledge of MySQL )

Comment: That's true, you need to copy ibdata1 with all the .ibd files for each table in a consistent fashion. That is, at the same moment, so the data dictionary stored in ibdata1 matches the structure of each table. Unfortunately, it might be too late to get a consistent copy of these file. My sympathies!

Comment: Thank you guys for informing me, because I tried so many times to getting back my database for very important project but it’s ok. A new lesson learned.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with MariaDB and MySQL. In my experience, it has happened at least 10 times a year on our servers.

No one can help you. None of the hints, tools, tips, hacks, repairsoftware, mysqlcheck, or mysqlrepair work. All of our tickets at MariaDB just ended with the necessity of reinstalling the database and restoring the data from the backup.

To me, this makes both of these databases a "no-go" for a production system, as it is unacceptable for a production system to periodically lose data without cause.